# Pythonic way to test if a row is in an array

Tags: arrays, testing, numpy, python

This seems like a simple question, but I haven't been able to find a good answer.

I'm looking for a pythonic way to test whether a 2d numpy array contains a given row. For example:

```
myarray = numpy.array([[0,1],
                       [2,3],
                       [4,5]])

myrow1 = numpy.array([2,3])
myrow2 = numpy.array([2,5])
myrow3 = numpy.array([0,3])
myrow4 = numpy.array([6,7])
```

Given myarray, I want to write a function that returns True if I test myrow1, and False if I test myrow2, myrow3 and myrow4.

I tried the "in" keyword, and it didn't give me the results I expected:

```
>>> myrow1 in myarray
True
>>> myrow2 in myarray
True
>>> myrow3 in myarray
True
>>> myrow4 in myarray
False
```

It seems to only check if one or more of the elements are the same, not if all elements are the same. Can someone explain why that's happening?

I can do this test element by element, something like this:

```
def test_for_row(array,row):
    numpy.any(numpy.logical_and(array[:,0]==row[0],array[:,1]==row[1]))
```

But that's not very pythonic, and becomes problematic if the rows have many elements. There must be a more elegant solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Pythonic" usually means terse and readable without any specific regard for performance.  Numpy best-practices usually have a high emphasis on performance.  @eat's solution is the the most "Numpytonic" solution as it avoids treating an array as python iterator.  Python loops over a Numpy array are usually avoided since there are usually more efficient alternatives.  See my comment in @eat's Answer for a solution with similar performance and better readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just simply subtract your test row from the array. Then find out the zero elements, and sum over column wise. Then those are matches where the sum equals the number of columns.

For example:

```
In []: A= arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
In []: A
Out[]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
In []: 3== (0== (A- [3, 4, 5])).sum(1)
Out[]: array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

**Update**: based on comments and other answers:
`Paul`'s suggestion seems indeed to be able to streamline code:

```
In []: ~np.all(A- [3, 4, 5], 1)
Out[]: array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

`JoshAdel`'s answer emphasis more generally the problem related to determine 100% reliable manner the equality. So, obviously my answer is valid only in the situations where equality can be determined unambiguous manner.

**Update 2**: But as `Emma` figured it out, there exists corner cases where `Paul`'s solution will not produce correct results.

Comment: A more readable alternative: `~np.all(A-B, axis=1)` (where B is `[3,4,5]`)

Comment: And then you could wrap @Paul's code in `np.any` to test if you have a matching row. As I mentioned in my answer, be careful though if you are dealing with floats instead of ints, because depending on how you assign the `myrow` variables, you might have issues with finite precision and another strategy will be necessary.

Comment: @Paul: Your answer will give false positives in the event that one or more (but not all) of the elements in B matches with one of the rows in A. For example, if we test `B = [3,0,0]`, `~np.all(A-B, axis=1)` returns `array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)`.

Comment: @eat and @Emma.  Crap.  That's no corner case, that's just bad logic.  It should be `~np.any(A-B, axis=1)`

Comment: @Paul: I guess you meant that `~np.all(A-B, axis=1)` is bad logic. However even that `~np.any(.)` will produce correct result, I, personally feel both `np.any(.)` and `np.all(.)` slightly cumbersome to work with, because they don't strictly operate with `booleans`, rather anything which can be understood as `boolean` in a sense that `0` represents `False` and everything else `True`. Thanks

Comment: It should be `any(all(A == B, axis=1))`.

Answer (score 5):

The SO question below should help you out, but basically you can use:

```
any((myrow1 == x).all() for x in myarray)
```

[Numpy.Array in Python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488307/numpy-array-in-python-list)

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalization of @maz's solution that handles floats more elegantly, where strict equality is going to fail:

```
import numpy as np

def test_for_row(myarray,row):
    return any(np.allclose(row,x) for x in myarray)
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html for details. Also as a side note, be careful that you haven't done something like `from numpy import *` since `np.any` and python's built-in `any` will result in different answers, the former being incorrect.

Comment: Please note that even `allclose(.)` based approach is not 'bullet proof'. I suggest not to generalize this question too much. Lets keep it in the level, where equality can really be determined unambiguous manner. Thanks

Comment: Anyone care to comment on why this deserves a -1?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and the following approach works for me

```
def is_row_in_matrix(row, matrix):
    return sum(np.prod(matrix == row, axis = 1))
```

Basically, test if each element of the row is in the corresponding column of the matrix, then multiply along the column `(axis = 1)`, and sum the result.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def row_in_array(myarray, myrow):
    return (myarray == myrow).all(-1).any()
```

This is what it looks like for your test cases:

```
myarray = numpy.array([[0,1],
                       [2,3],
                       [4,5]])

row_in_array(myarray, [2, 3])
# True
row_in_array(myarray, [2, 5])
# False
row_in_array(myarray, [0, 3])
# False
row_in_array(myarray, [6, 7])
# False
```