# How to check if an array is in a list of arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list of 3x3 arrays `l` and I want to check if a different single 3x3 array `a` is in the list. I tried like this:

```
a in l
```

but it couldn't be executed beacuse of the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I cannot grasp why such a comparison would be ambiguous (the intention is clear), but anyway, is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: Could you add some sample data?

Comment: Are you using Numpy?

Comment: This similar SO post may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: The map and id solution did not work for me, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979146/check-if-numpy-array-is-in-list-of-numpy-arrays) did.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy is confused there on what you want to do. Do you want to know if `a` is equivalent to any element of `l` or if `a` is an element of `l`.

```
a  = np.ones((3,3))
b = np.ones((3,3))
l  = [b]


b in l
>>True

a in l
>>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-cf48b78477bf> in <module>()
----> 1 a in l

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

An alternative for this, if you want to know if `a` is in `l` is to use `id()` function.

so

```
ids = map(id, l)

id(a) in ids
>> False

id(b) in ids
>>True
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the difference here:  "if a is equivalent to any element of l or if a is an element of l"? If a is any element of l then a is an element of l right?

Comment: I meant, there are two specific cases to consider here : 1. if `a` is similar to an element of `l`, meaning `a` contains same thing as an element in `l`. and 2. if `a` is an element of `l`. Example: if `l` is a list of cars, `a = "red car"`, now 1. if you assign `l =["red car","yellow car"]` then `a` is equivalent (equal) to an element of `l` but if you change the value of `a`, `a = "blue car"`, now `a` is not equal to any element of `l` but if `l` was defined as `l =[a]`, then you can do what ever to `a` and `a in l` will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

`a.all()` and `a.any()` could only be done using numpy. Now numpy needs to know if you'd consider it a match if -

- `any` - any of the elements match
- `all` - all of the elements match

Its not about intentions. Its about providing functions that the community would find helpful. So in your case you'd probably use `a.all`
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472814/use-a-any-or-a-all) SO post should clear it up for you. I essentially provided the gist above.

Answer (score 0):

It worked well on my side when I tried it, but I found some returns that were inaccurate.

```
a= np.ones((3,3))
b= np.ones((3,3))

a in b
#output True

b in a 
#output True
```

but when I changed the length of arrays in one, and not the other some discrepancies came out.

```
a= np.ones((3,3))
b= np.ones((4,3))

a in b
#Output- False    #this was the same for the reverse

np.any(a ==b)
#Output False   #This also threw up a depreciation warning forelementwise == comparison

np.any(a[0] == b[0])
#OutPut True

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in b[i]:
        print('yes')
#OutPut   yes yes yes
```

seems it doesn't like comparing an array of array's as much as it likes doing it one by one.