# Check if one of the rows in numpy array exists in the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, append

I am using python-3.x and I would like to check if one of the numpy array rows in my_array_3 exists in the dictionary dic_t by trying the following way:

```
my_array_3[2] in dic_t.values()
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Also, I am trying to append this numpy array row to the dictionary under the key "array_1" by trying the following way:

```
dic_t["array_1"].append(my_array_3[2])
```

but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I am not sure where the problem is and how to solve it since I tried different ways.

the full code is:

```
import numpy as np

# my first array
my_array_1 = np.array([[1 , 2, 3],
                [32, 42, 11],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [32, 42, 11],
                [1 , 2, 3]])

# my second array
my_array_2 = np.array([[23],[33],[45],[45],[45], [33], [23]])

# here I want to find the unique values index from my_array_1
_, my_array_1_indx = np.unique(my_array_1, return_index=True, axis=0)

# here I want to returen the unique values sorted from my_array_1
my_array_1_uniq = (my_array_1[np.sort(my_array_1_indx)])

# here I want to returen the unique values sorted from my_array_2 based on the my_array_1_indx
my_array_2_uniq = (my_array_2[np.sort(my_array_1_indx)])

#save the result to dictionary
dic_t= {"array_1": my_array_1_uniq,
      "array_2": my_array_2_uniq}



my_array_3 = np.array([[23 , 4, 2],
                [32, 42, 11],
                [54, 1, 9],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [34, 67, 77],
                [1 , 2, 3]])



# now I want to check if one of the rows in my_array_3 exists in the dictionary dic_t
for i in range (len(my_array_3)):
#    here the first error   ******
    if my_array_3[i] in dic_t.values():

        print ( my_array_3[i], " deleted")
        my_array_3 = np.delete(my_array_3, (i), axis=0)

    else:
        print ( my_array_3[i], " added")

#       here the second error  ******
        dic_t["array_1"].append(my_array_3[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working answer with two modifications:

- First, you are checking for occurrence of a 1-d array in a list of arrays. This can be done using `any` and `all` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488307/numpy-array-in-python-list)
- Second, you need to use `vstack` to insert/append a row to your array.

---

```
for i in range (len(my_array_3)):
    if any((my_array_3[i] == j).all() for j in dic_t.values()):
        print ( my_array_3[i], " deleted")
        my_array_3 = np.delete(my_array_3, (i), axis=0)
    else:
        print ( my_array_3[i], " added")
        dic_t["array_1"] = np.vstack((dic_t["array_1"], my_array_3[i]))

# [23  4  2]  added
# [32 42 11]  added
# [54  1  9]  added
# [ 9 21 22]  added
# [ 9 21 22]  added
# [34 67 77]  added
# [1 2 3]  added
```

Comment: How to identify the Index number of dic_t.values() if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

**This the final solution if someone needs it** (Thanks to @Sheldore)

```
# import numpy
import numpy as np

# my first array
my_array_1 = np.array([[1 , 2, 3],
                [32, 42, 11],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [32, 42, 11],
                [1 , 2, 3]])

# my second array
my_array_2 = np.array([[23],[33],[45],[45],[45], [33], [23]])

# here I want to find the unique values index from my_array_1
_, my_array_1_indx = np.unique(my_array_1, return_index=True, axis=0)

# here I want to returen the unique values sorted from my_array_1
my_array_1_uniq = (my_array_1[np.sort(my_array_1_indx)])

# here I want to returen the unique values sorted from my_array_2 based on the my_array_1_indx
my_array_2_uniq = (my_array_2[np.sort(my_array_1_indx)])

#save the result to dictionary
dic_t= {"array_1": my_array_1_uniq,
      "array_2": my_array_2_uniq}



my_array_3 = np.array([[23 , 4, 2],
                [32, 42, 11],
                [54, 1, 9],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [9, 21, 22],
                [34, 67, 77],
                [1 , 2, 3]])



i=0
while i < len(my_array_3):

    print ("\n *****************************************************", i)

    if any((my_array_3[i] == j).all() for j in dic_t["array_1"]):

#        print (my_array_3[i])
#        print ( my_array_3[i], " deleted")
        my_array_3 = np.delete(my_array_3, (i), axis=0)

        print (" deleted")
#        print (" lingh :", lingh)


    else:

        print ( my_array_3[i], " added")
        dic_t["array_1"] = np.vstack((dic_t["array_1"], my_array_3[i])) 

        i+=1
```

Result :

```
 ***************************************************** 0
[23  4  2]  added

 ***************************************************** 1
 deleted

 ***************************************************** 1
[54  1  9]  added

 ***************************************************** 2
 deleted

 ***************************************************** 2
 deleted

 ***************************************************** 2
[34 67 77]  added

 ***************************************************** 3
 deleted
```